# Symfony2 force subform validation when every field is empty

Tags: forms, validation, symfony, callback

I have two entities (let's call them A and B) bound in a one to one relatioship and a form to populate them.
B entity fields are populated depending on a state in entity A as follows:

entity A: state 0
entity B: both fields empty

entity A: state 1
entity B: field 1 filled field 2 empty

entity A: state 2
entity B: field 1 empty field 2 filled

Both fields filled state is not allowed.

So I made 3 custom callback validators to check states 1, 2 and not allowed.
Unfortunately checking on states 1 and 2 is not triggered when both fields are empty, clearly because fields are empty; infact adding a fake hidden field to the form triggers validation process, because form is populated!

Obviously this is a hackish solution, so I was wondering if there is a way to force subform validation even when every form field is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Symfony does not validate forms, it validates entities.  Your best best is to make a validation function in your entities and validate using symfony's 'Getters' validation described here:

http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/book/validation.html#getters

I believe for your case, the entity that has the validation is the one associated with the form type.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. However I already have a callback validation method called by @Assert\Callbacks annotation. So I'd prefer to use this method to set an error message to the proper field or fields.